# Vue: how to construct a component with a custom v-slot dom?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-component

Now I have a custom Component, and I use a custom render function:

```html
<script>
export default {
  render(h) {
    return h('InnerComponent', h('div', 'My Content'))
  }
}
</script>
```

and the `InnerComponent` is defined as below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Default slot: <slot></slot></div>
    <div>Custom slot: <slot name="custom"></slot></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

So the content `h('div', 'My Content')` was injected into the default slot, and finally rendered as below:

```html
<div>
  <div>Default slot: <div>My Content</div></div>
  <div>Custom slot: </div>
</div>
```

So what if I want to inject that content into the custom slot? (`<slot name="custom"></slot>`), inside the render function, like we use as in the below template?

```html
<template>
  <InnerComponent>
    <div v-slot:custom>My Content</div>
  </InnerComponent>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

You just need to specify a `slot` in the child's options:

```js
h('div', { slot: 'custom' }, 'My Content')
```